# VBA saveas newly created Excel sheet using old Word Document's title

Tags: vba, excel

I can create a new workbook by using the method

```
workbooks.add
```

However, I need to save it with the same file name as the previous Word document which I manually copied all the useful data into it.

I have done some research into this and have found out about this method in VBA called

```
saveas
```

but whenever I try, it fails to save the new file with the same name as the Word document.

This was my code...

```
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim LatestFile As String
Dim LatestDate As Date
Dim LMD As Date  

Workbooks.Add


MyPath = "D:\Analysis\"
If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"

'this line below selects the word file to be chosen
MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.docx", vbNormal)

'If no files were found, exit the sub
If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If

'Loop through each word file in the folder
Do While Len(MyFile) > 0

    'Assign the date/time of the current file to a variable
    LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)

    'If the date/time of the current file is greater than the latest
    'recorded date, assign its filename and date/time to variables
    If LMD > LatestDate Then
        LatestFile = MyFile
        LatestDate = LMD
    End If

    'Get the next word file from the folder
    MyFile = Dir
    Loop

 wdFileName = MyPath & LatestFile

(extra code here)
(extra code here)

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=wdFileName, _
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

**(the last 2 lines of code do not seem to have any effect at all and it does not save the Excel with the same title name as the Word document I get my data from)**

As I'm still new in VBA, help would be much appreciated with thanks!

Please do provide clear code to aid in my learning.

Comment: `wdFileName = MyPath & LatestFile` sets `wdFileName` to `""` because `MyPath` and  `LatestFile` are not yet defined. You have to set `wdFileName` after you have set the other variables. It does not change later if you change `MyPath` and `LatestFile`. Also why is it not a String? Oh and I forgot that you should probably not save your Workbook as a .docx file ;)

Comment: @arcadeprecinct if im not wrong, string and variant do not have much difference. you can check this out! [link] (http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/17237-variant-data-type-vs-string-data-type.html) Also, i think i mentioned that what i wanted to do was to save the excel file as an excel file except that it had the same name as the word file i obtained my data from. Apologies if that wasn't clear :)

Comment: If there's no need for a variant I would recommend a String instead. Unless you expect really long filenames. I would think that if your Word file is named "File1.docx" you want your workbook to be saved as "File1.xlsx"? Edit: I see that you moved `wdFileName=...`, does it work then?

Comment: @arcadeprecinct yes youre right on all points. my filenames are really long. an example of one of my files would be 20160523141534_drawing. the numbers are basically yyyy/mm/dd/hh/mm/ss. i did move the wdFileName=... but it still cant work for me :( do you have any idea?

Comment: I assume there is an error message? Check what wdFileName is set to before saveas using the debugger or a msgbox.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct there is no error message adn the wdFileName is todays date with a docx. I cant still get it to work though can you help?

Comment: You can't save a workbook as a docx file. Word will say that it is corrupted. `wdFileName = Left(wdFileName, Len(wdFileName)-4) & "xlsx"` or `Replace(wdFileName,".docx",".xlsx")`should change the ending. The code still produces a docx file for me though. Maybe you're looking in the wrong folder? btw: I think strings can hold up to 2 billion characters so your filenames should be fine.